# unresolved external symbol _CLSID_VdsLoader

Tags: windows, com, visual-c++-2013, vds

I'm trying to write a program that can manage the harddisks/volumes/partitions in a Windows system. It seemed like a good idea to use Windows' Virtual Disk Service to accomplish this.

I wrote a bit of code to try it out, but when linking it I get the following error: `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_VdsLoader`

Microsofts [sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383037.aspx) indicates that I have to link to ole32.lib, and from googling I learned that uuid.lib is also involved. The "Additional Dependencies" line in my project settings is the following:

`kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)`

As you can see, both previously mentioned libraries are included.

I'm trying all this on Visual C++ Express for Windows Desktop 2013. Could this be the problem? Perhaps the express version does not support 100% of the available COM objects? If that's not it, what else could it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained here: [How to avoid error "LNK2001 unresolved external" by using DEFINE_GUID](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_KB_Archive/130869), you just need for example to add `#include <InitGuid.h>` in your stdafx.h file.

Comment: Just tried including it, and I still get the same error. Thanks for trying.

Comment: The point is that it must be added to `stdafx.h` file and not in wherever else (your .cpp or .h files). Thanks @Simon

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with unresolved external guid. I didn't define `_MIDL_USE_GUIDDEF_` macro and tried to compile code as C++ code.

Since MIDL compiler generates C source file to define guids it is compiled as C code until you explicitly tell visual studio to compile code as C++ code.

MIDL-generated header file contains (when compiled as C++):

```
extern "C"
{
    extern "C" const IID iid;   // extern "C" is redundant, extern would be enough
}
```

MIDL-generated guids-definition file contains (when compiled as C++):

```
extern "C"
{
    const IID iid = { ... };    // _MIDL_USE_GUIDDEF_ macro is not defined
}
```

We need to remember:

```
extern "C" block implies C name decoration; e.g.
  extern "C" { int a; }

extern "C" singleton implies C name decoration AND extern semantics; e.g.
  extern "C" int a;

in C++ non-extern namespace-scope const object implies internal linkage; e.g.
  const int a;         // internal linkage
  extern const int b;  // external linkage
```

With this in mind we can see that header file declares `const IID iid` with external linkage and C name decoration, whereas guids-definition file defines `const IID iid` with internal linkage and C name decoration. Linkages do not match, therefore they are treated as different entities by linker. In this case `const IID iid` with external linkage is left undefined and is later used in the same translation unit.

When you add predefined `_MIDL_USE_GUIDDEF_` macro guids-definition file will contain:

```
extern "C"
{
    extern "C" const IID iid = { ... };    // extern "C" is redundant, extern would be enough
}
```

So you need to add predefined `_MIDL_USE_GUIDDEF_` macro in order to explicitly compile code as C++.